# Replace strings and update file using sed from python

Tags: python, sed

Im trying to replace the first line of a file which has double quotes.
The File contains something like this:

```
"A"|"B"|"C"
"1"|"2"|"3"
```

I want to create or update the file to show something as follows (first line without double quotes):

```
A|B|C
"1"|"2"|"3"
```

Typically this can be done using bash with sed:

```
sed 's/"A"|"B"|"C"/A|B|C/g' inputfile.txt> outputfile.txt
```

I want to implement it from python using subprocess.call()

My code:

```
subprocess.call(["sed", 's/"A"|"B"|"C"/A|B|C/g', "inputfile.txt", ">", "outputfile.txt"])
```

But it throws an error:

```
sed: can't read >: No such file or directory
sed: can't read outputfile.txt: No such file or directory
```

I guess I have to create the file outputfile.txt first, but i want to do it all from python.
Can you help me please, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling `sed` from within `python`? Why not use `python`'s own string manipulation methods?

Comment: You can't use `>` when the argument is a list. That's a shell feature, so you have to use a string with `shell=True`.

Comment: @match I know how to do it .. but I want this specific method. Thanks

Comment: `subprocess.call(["sed 's/"A"|"B"|"C"/A|B|C/g' inputfile.txt> outputfile.txt"], shell=True)`

@Barmar I used this method .. but for some reason is not working, probably a confusion with double quotes and single quotes

Comment: You need to escape the inner double quotes.

Comment: `sed '1s/"//g' file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `>` redirection you need to use `shell=True` and a single string argument, not a list.

```
subprocess.call("""sed 's/"A"|"B"|"C"/A|B|C/g' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt""", shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I was missing the quotes when I tried this method.
Best regards.

Comment: You also had extra `[]`.